# Does this .gitignore laravel makes sense when you're working with a team?

Tags: github, gitignore

I start using `Github` 2 days ago, and it's in a private repository.

So I with my friend (I appointed him as Collaborator) working a project together, but what is the best setting for `.gitignore` file when you're working with a team?
Because what I'm thinking is, if `Github` ignore file such as `.env` (the app key) & `/vendor`, the program wouldn't work as what it must to be right?

for now I using the default setting of `.gitignore` files.

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea
/.vscode
/.vagrant
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
.env
```

Please help, I already search about it but I can't get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to start with the recommendation form [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/).
See [`gitignore.io/api/laravel`](https://www.gitignore.io/api/laravel)

#### Laravel

/vendor
node_modules/
npm-debug.log

```
# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
storage/*.key
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json

# Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
.rocketeer/
```

Note that ignoring *folders* should be specified as `aFolder/`, with a trailing slash.

Any folder with *generated* content should be ignored.
If `vendor/` is *not generated (but includes sources that you need to compile), then you should *not* ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, this is the explanation that I'm looking for!

Comment: So the website you mentioned, is the best `.gitignore` option for a starter? but why does it ignore the `.env.php` & `.env.*.php` file? because I never see a `.env` file have a `.php` extension on it?

PS: and thanks for the edit to my question, it makes a lot better

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya This is specific to Lumen, a PHP Micro-framework (https://lumen.laravel.com/). If you don't use PHP, feel free to adapt that generic `.gitignore` to your specific case.